# Finding and substituting set of codes/words in a file based on a list of old and corrected ones

Tags: r, file, data-cleaning, substitution

I have a `FASTA_16S.txt` file containing paragraphs of different lengths with a unique code (e.g. 16S317) at the top. After transfer into `R`, I have a list with 413 members that looks like this:

```
[1]">16S317_V._rotiferianus_A\n
AAATTGAAGAGTTTGATCATGGCTCAG..."
[2]">16S318_Salmonella_bongori\n
AAATTGAAGAGTTTGATCATGGCTCAGATT..."
[3]">16S319_Escherichia_coli\n
TTGAAGAGTTTGATCATGGCTCAGATTG...
```

I need to substitute the existing codes with the new ones from a table `Code_16S`:

```
     Old    New
 1. 16S317 16S001
 2. 16S318 16S307 
 3. 16S319 16S211
 4.  ...    ...
```

Can anybody suggest a code that would identify an old code and substitute it with a new one?
Consider that we have the same codes in columns New and Old, so direct application of `gsub` or `replace` for the whole list did not work (after a substitution we have two paragraphs with the same code, so one of the next steps will change both of them).

Below there is my solution for the problem, but I don´t consider it as an optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `lapply`, it may be easier with `str_replace_all`

```
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
FASTA_16S <- str_replace_all(FASTA_16S, deframe(Code_16S))
```

-output

```
FASTA_16S
[1] ">16S001_V._rotiferianus_A\n\nAAATTGAAGAGTTTGATCATGGCTCAG..."   
[2] ">16S307_Salmonella_bongori\n\nAAATTGAAGAGTTTGATCATGGCTCAGATT..."
```

#### data

```
FASTA_16S <- c(">16S317_V._rotiferianus_A\n\nAAATTGAAGAGTTTGATCATGGCTCAG...", 
">16S318_Salmonella_bongori\n\nAAATTGAAGAGTTTGATCATGGCTCAGATT..."
)
Code_16S <- structure(list(Old = c("16S317", "16S318", "16S319"), New = c("16S001", 
"16S307", "16S211")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1.", 
"2.", "3."))
```

Comment: This was helpful! I have tried `str_replace_all`, but without `structure` in non-organized file it was giving an error. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As long as **the new codes are sorted according to the old ones**, which corresponds to the order of the paragraphs in the file, we can perform substitution paragraph by paragraph.
(Initially the table was sorted by the column `New`)

```
Num = seq.int(1:413)   # total number of paragraphs
Code_16S = codes$New   

F_16S = function(x) {
  row = code_16S[x]
  gsub("^.{7}", paste(">", row, sep = ""), FASTA_16S[[1]][x])
}

N_16S = lapply(Num, F_16S)
```

With `gsub("^[>].{7}",` I tried to substitute first 6 characters (the code) except the first one (`>`) in each string, but it did not work, thus added `paste` function.